# MVC post action some fields are null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have MVC action to create a record in the database.

some fields are filled by the user, and some other filled by ajax call (3'rd party), after I got success response I use jquery to fill the fields back on the form (such as text box and assign a value for a drop-down list), this happens on the client side.

The Form in client side is working fine, validation is working fine too.

Example how i filling the fields on client side after ajax response success call :

```
$("#location").val(response.location);
```

the problem is when I click on save and reach the `Create Action (POST)`, I found the fields which filled by jquery (such as location) is coming Null, but the fields which filled by the user have values.

note: all fields exist inside the form `(@Html.Beginform)`.

Comment: Please add your relevant code?

Comment: Without seeing your code it's pretty much impossible to know what you might have done wrong. Please add the relevant information

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reply guys, 
i just discover the problem it was little strange.
actually when i define these fields (which will filled by ajax call), i define it as the following : 
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CurrentLoyalPoints, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled", @PlaceHolder = Resources.Captions.CurrentLoyalPoints} }) ,

and the issue is using the disabled, i just replace it with  @readonly = "readonly".

Things work very fine now as expected.

Comment: That's not strange. The HTML spec says that disabled fields are not submitted as part of the form data. It's well documented. Your page is behaving as intended.